# How to draw a JPanel on a canvas?

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

is there a possibility to draw a JPanel on a specific location op a Graphics (or Graphics2D) object?
I override the paint method of my canvas, and call panel.paint(g) in there, but it does not work the way I woul hope.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
  Dimension size = panel.getPreferredSize();
  panel.setBounds(pos.x, pos.y, size.width, size.height);
  panel.paint(g);
}
```

the size object is correctly defined as I would wish, so that's not the problem. Also, the pos contains a correct x and y on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, since the latter is the AWT method, and the former is the Swing method.

One nice thing about Swing's `paintComponent` is that the `Graphics` passed is actually always going to be a `Graphics2D`, so you can:

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)lg;
```

Now you can use the `getTransform` to save the old transform, then modify the transform of the `Graphics2D` using either `setTranform` or the `scale`, `translate` and `rotate` methods. Don't forget to **restore the old transform**, or you'll likely fudge the next thing being drawn by that context.

Comment: I replaced the paint by paintComponent, and used the transform to move the panel to another location. But nothing gets painted...

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in that, depending on the circumstance, drawing to a BufferedImage might be appropriate. You can get a Graphics context using BufferedImage.getGraphics(). Then you can draw the BufferedImage's context by whatever means suit you.

Comment: Can I convert a panel to a BufferedImage? Or what is the missing link here?

Comment: maybe createImage(int width, int height)?
But this returns null in my case